# Интерфейсы и абстрактные классы в ООП

Tags: ооп

На хабре в комментариях к одному посту о проведении собеседований разрослась [ветка](http://habrahabr.ru/post/169949/#comment_5898063) об интерфейсах и абстрактных классах.

А теперь классические вопросы:
Чем отличаются интерфейсы от абстрактных классов? Плюсы-минусы тех и других? В каких ситуациях выбирать интерфейсы, а в каких абстрактные классы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Абстрактный класс - основа некой иерархии классов.
Интерфейс - контракт, который должен выполняться классом, его реализующим.

Все остальное наподобие того, что абстрактные классы могут иметь поля и не только абстрактные методы, является уже вторичным, и скорее следствием из приведенного выше. О плюсах и минусах рассуждать считаю некорректным, так как это разные сущности, похожесть которых в большей степени внешняя